# How to locales word in side export default?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have been trying to change the language from English to others,

```
$t('bascketball')
```

↑this works inside the template, however I am looking the way that I can change the language of elements inside of export Default.

If you know how to solve it, please advice me.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      Games: [
      keyword: '',
      games: [
        {
          heading: $t('Basketball'),
          text:
            "Hello Basketball players, want to know about team members. Click Below.",
          img:
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQt0Sh97iYcu0kTguhcsW_szWfzolqu1ynGeQ&usqp=CAU",
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one of these:

```
this.$t('Basketball')

this.$i18n.tc('Basketball')
```

But because you're calling the API, you cannot do it in `data`, you can rewrite it to a computed method, like that:

```
computed: {
 games() {
  return [
    {
      heading: this.$t('Basketball'),
      text:
        "Hello Basketball players, want to know about team members. Click Below.",
      img:
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQt0Sh97iYcu0kTguhcsW_szWfzolqu1ynGeQ&usqp=CAU",
    }
  ]
 }
}
```